# how do i optimise this code of finding a number X whose sum with its digit is equal to n?

Tags: python

Find a Number X whose sum with its digits is equal to N

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n//2, n):

z = [int(x) for x in str(i)]
zz = sum(z)
if zz<=100:
    ans = int(i) + int(zz)
     if(int(i) + int(zz) == n) :
        print(i)
```

tile limit is exceeding

Comment: Can it be any number?

Comment: If (as seems likely to me) you have a problem with the algorithm rather than the code, see https://cs.stackexchange.com/ or https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If it can be any number, this would be a fast way to do it.

```
i = int(input("Your number: "))
result = ""

while i > 9:
    result += "9"
    i -= 9

result += str(i)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
for k in range(1000):

    if sum([int(i) for i in str(k)]) == k:
        print(k)
```

But there seem to be only very few numbers with that property...